# Not Found 404 use Annotation MountPath Page Wicket

Tags: wicket

I have condition like this:
Use `@MountPath`:

```
@MountPath("admin/")
public class AdminPage extends SecurePage {
```

and in custom class from `WebApplication`, I mount the page like:

```
final MountPath mountPath = Preconditions.checkNotNull(page.getAnnotation(MountPath.class),
                "Page class %s does not have @MountPath/@ManageMountPath/@OpenMountPath annotation", page.getName());
mountPage(mountPath.value(), page);
```

and run `/admin/` is OK, but if I run `/admin` is Not Found (404).

So I tested for `mountPage("admin", HomeBackEndPage.class);` directly, and 404 is gone for `/admin/` or `/admin`.

I tink, I missed somethin.. Please help....

env:

```
<wicket.version>7.7.0</wicket.version>
```

Comment: I guess wicketstuff annotation? Seems U use two "technologies" to one goal https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Annotation annotation is useless without initialisation

Comment: Yup @JacekCz, I used ```org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount.MountPath``` in ```wicketstuff-annotation-7.8.0-sources.jar```. Thank you for your suggestion, I should try it...

Comment: IMO you can do wicket itself no need `wicketstuff annotation`

Comment: @soorapadman mount-class annotation had been integrated into core? Tell few words more (agree, wicket has "manual" mount from the beginning)

Comment: @JacekCz  Sorry i meant other way . I just meant to achieve mount page we can do in wicket itself . I don't think annotation added into core. May be in future release will check with  Martin-g. To answer this question The link which you shared its well enough my opinion.